# Vector bundle on spec of Artin local ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, vector-bundles

Let $A$ be a local Artin $k$-algebra with residue field $k$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field.

> Is it true that all vector bundles on $Spec(A)$ are trivial?

I guess the commutative algebra question is : are locally free modules globally free on such rings?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since [projective modules over a local ring are free](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/058Z).